# iphone uitableview populate - program exits without warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios4

I'm parsing data from a remote database to an iphone application and populating the table view. The program is able to populate the table view fine however its all the records. To sort the records i was advised to use `NSPredicate` to sort the data (which works) but when it tries to load the data, the program exists with no warnings in the console. I dont understand why, could someone have a quick glance over the code and tell me where im going wrong? (i think its something to do with these lines `return [rows count];` and `NSDictionary *dict = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];`). Thanks for any help on this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your viewDidLoad, retain the array and try.

```
    rows = [[courses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] retain];
```

Comment: it works :o, could you explain to me why it is working with the retain part please?

Comment: filteredArrayUsingPredicate returns an autorelease object. Every event is surrounded in an autorelease pool, so the object is released if you don't increment the retain count with the retain message. Remember to release the object in your dealloc method. Make good use of the Analyze tool that you find in the Product menu.

Answer (score 1):

You should retain the rows array since filteredArrayUsingPredicate should return an autorelease object.

Comment: For instance: self.rows=[courses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];